# cron срабатывает только после обновления страницы

Tags: php, cron

Поставил PHP файл к cron, но не работает. Перешел по ссылке, где находиться файл cron: `сайт.ру/файл-крон.php`, также не срабатывает, а если обновить эту страницу, то работает. Это ошибка в php файле или что-то еще.
Вот cron:
`/usr/bin/php /var/www/userID/data/www/сайт.ру/actions/файл-крон.php`

Comment: приложите к вопросу листинг файла `/etc/crontab`

Comment: попробуйте выполнить приведённую вами команду в оболчке (shell) сервера и расскажите, что получается.